# Measuring distance with steps

Tags: mathematics, probability

I am trying to measure 100m for a children's foot race, but I forgot to bring my measuring wheel. I know that each of my steps is between 0.9m and 1.1m (sampled at uniform). I can only take full steps - no half steps. I also have an unlimited supply of cones that I can place on the ground. How can I measure 100m or as close as possible to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Measure 100 full steps and mark the end point with a cone. Do this a large odd number of times, let's say 1001 (or 2n+1). Then, starting with the cone nearest to your starting point, count 501 (or n+1) cones in order. The 501st nearest cone is your 100-metre marker. The larger your number of attempts, the closer this cone should be to exactly 100m.

Comment: Correct! That's the approach I had in mind.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky That said, for a children's foot race I'd probably just measure it once and call that 100m :P

Comment: So, the answer is median of many samples?

Comment: @Jafe yeah that probably works too :)

Comment: @justhalf yep pretty much. I was thinking that there could be another pass between the smallest and largest samples to converge faster to the 100, but not sure that it would be faster.